# jquery simplemodal unable to call another function

Tags: jquery, simplemodal, jquery-callback

In my modal window I have a "continue" button. Whilst I can get the modal to close by assigning the button with the simplemodal-close class, I can't get it to call my function. I've put together this code from the simple demos on the site.

The button:

```
<a href="#" class="simplemodal-close" onClick="closePopup()"><img src="bell/images/button_understand.gif" width="116" height="49"></a>
```

the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function showPopups(){
        var e = document.getElementById('hirpopup');
        $('#hirpopup').modal({
        opacity:80,
        overlayCss: {backgroundColor:"#fff"}
        });
    e.style.display = 'block';
    return false;
    }

    function closePopup(){
        var e = document.getElementById('hirpopup');
        e.style.display = 'none';

        confirm(function () {
        sameWindow(this.form);
        });
    }

    function confirm(callback) {
        $('#hirpopup').modal({
            onShow: function () {
                var modal = this;
                // call the callback
                if ($.isFunction(callback)) {
                    callback.apply();
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Any ideas as I'm pretty new to jQuery and completely new to simplemodal.

EDIT: I've updated my javascript as follows, however its still not doing my function. I get the alert of 1, and the alert with the function in it but nothing else.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#close").css("cursor", "pointer"); 

    $('#next').click(function(){
        var e = document.getElementById('hirpopup');
        $('#hirpopup').modal({
            opacity:80,
            overlayCss: {backgroundColor:"#fff"}
        });
        e.style.display = 'block';
        return false;
    });

    $('#close').click(function(){
        var e = document.getElementById('hirpopup');
        e.style.display = 'none';

        confirm(function () {
            sameWindow(this.form);
        });
    });
});


function confirm(callback) {
alert("1");
alert(callback);
    $('#hirpopup').modal({
        onShow: function () {
            alert("2");
            var modal = this;
            // call the callback
            if ($.isFunction(callback)) {
                alert("3");
                callback.apply();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Where your showPopups is called?

Comment: "Where your showPopups is called?" - In the onClick event of a different anchor tag on the same page have "return showPopups();"

Comment: By code reading I see no problem. My opinion is: move to jQuery event binding as you are already using it on your page. Log and/or alert your code.

Comment: I've added my amended code, but its still not processing my callback. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: you may try to put confirm method inside document.ready. This could be one issue

You cannot have $(document).ready inside your own function, but it should be the root method. Use also the jQuery event binding

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

$('.simplemodal-close').click({

        var e = document.getElementById('hirpopup');
        e.style.display = 'none';

        confirm(function () {
            sameWindow(this.form);
        });

});
```

});

Comment: As I said to Chinmayee, I tried removing those lines and now my showPopups is being ignored. I've updated my code in the original post to reflect what I have currently.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have  `$(document).ready(function(){})` inside your function. It executes automatically only once when your page gets loaded.

instead write

```
function closePopup(){

        var e = document.getElementById('hirpopup');
        e.style.display = 'none';

        confirm(function () {
            sameWindow(this.form);
        });

}
```

Comment: I changed the code and now my showPopups method call is being ignored. I've updated the code in my post so you can see what I'm working with.